# Sum of digits present at even and odd positions

Tags: c, sum

```
int sumeven = 0, sumodd = 0, num, remainder, c;
scanf("%d", &num);
c = 0;
while (num) {
    remainder = num % 10;
    c++;
    if (c % 2 == 0) {
        sumeven = sumeven + remainder;
    } else
    if(c % 2 != 0) {
        sumodd = sumodd + remainder;
    }
    num = num / 10;
}
printf("sum of digits at even pos: %d\n sum of digits at odd pos: %d", 
       sumeven, sumodd);
```

So the problem is when there is an odd number of digits in `num`, the program works perfectly, it gives the sum of numbers at even positions and odd positions separately but the problem arises when there is an even number of digits. When there is an even number of digits, the `sumeven` stores the sum of odd digits and vice versa. Why does this happen and how to fix it?

A little searching online and I came to know this could be fixed adding the following code after the while loop

```
if (c % 2 == 0) {
    temp = sumeven;
    sumeven = sumodd;
    sumodd = temp;
}
```

but I don't get how this code works (I know it interchanges `sumeven` and `sumodd` but why does it do so when `c` is even?)

Comment: By position you mean starting from 5 in a number like 12345 or from 1?

Comment: For example the number is 1234, sumeven should store 2+4 ie 6 and similiary sumodd should store 1+3 ie 4.

Comment: I think J...S is onto something: are you counting from the left? Your code counts from the right. This would explain what you describe.

Comment: Oh shoot. Correct. It counts from the right! Major mess up by me. How to fix it though? An explanation (don't care about the code) would be awesome. thank you.

Comment: I figured it out, thank you guys. Today I learned that a small mess up can lead to a disappointment for hours!

Answer (score 2):

very simple answer you count from the end not from the beginning, so for the odd number of digits you need to swap the result.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(long long n, unsigned *odd, unsigned *even)
{
    int e = 0;
    int digit;
    *odd = *even = 0;
    while(n)
    {
        digit = n % 10;
        if(e & 1) 
            *even += digit;
        else 
            *odd += digit;
        n /= 10;
        e++;
    }
    if(e & 1)
    {
        unsigned tmp = *odd;
        *odd = *even;
        *even = tmp;
    }
    return e;
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned e,o;

    int num = sum(123, &o, &e);
    printf("num = %d    odd = %d\teven = %d\n", num, o, e);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Figured! Thank you.